# QGIS 3.4.5-1 'Madeira' doesn't launch

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

This has been probably asked many times before; looking for answers to no avail. After first click this is what I get ...

[image: First alert]

then this ...

[image: 2nd alert]

I'm still stuck with QGIS 2.18 'Las Palmas'

I'm not savvy with programming or computer science or anything in that sphere. I'm a landscape architect who happens to use QGIS for variety of analyses but definitely not as intense as GIS professionals.

Comment: Have you tried the basic stuff?

1. Uninstall all versions of QGIS 3 (dont uninstall qgis 2.18). Make sure that there is no data in Program files\QGIS3.4 and then re install QGIS 3.6. Check if this works.

2. Run QGIS as an admin and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your suggestion. Same outcome.